# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Shiba'

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to run the following [example](http://shibaapi.github.io/shiba/Getting%20started.html#i-want-an-example) from [Shiba](https://github.com/ShibaAPI/shiba) but keep running into the following error:

`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\test.py", line 1, in <module>
    from Shiba.shibaconnection import ShibaConnection
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Shiba'`

I found this excellent [guide](https://www.daveoncode.com/2017/03/07/how-to-solve-python-modulenotfound-no-module-named-import-error/) on the infamous `ModuleNotFoundError` but still can't seem to get it to work. Any ideas?

Shiba is installed:

[image]

And here is the shibaconnection.py module :

```
`from __future__ import unicode_literals

login = 'xxxx'
pwd = 'xxxx'

from shiba.salesManagement import salesManagement

class ShibaConnection(object):
    """The main Shiba class, standing as an initialization and mandatory for each submodules instancing.

        :param login: PriceMinister Seller login
        :param pwd: PriceMinister Seller Token \
        (see more at https://developer.priceminister.com/blog/fr/documentation/identification-by-token)
        :param sandbox: give it True if you want to test the API on a sandboxed version of PriceMinister.
        """

    def __init__(self, login, pwd, sandbox=False):
        self.login = str(login)
        self.pwd = str(pwd)
        self.domain = "https://ws.priceminister.com" if sandbox is False else "https://ws.sandbox.priceminister.com"
        self.actionsinfo = {
            "producttypes": {"cat": "stock_ws", "version": "2011-11-29", "login": self.login, "pwd": self.pwd},
            "producttypetemplate": {"cat": "stock_ws", "version": "2013-05-14", "login": self.login, "pwd": self.pwd},
            "genericimportfile": {"cat": "stock_ws", "version": "2012-09-11", "login": self.login, "pwd": self.pwd},
            "genericimportreport": {"cat": "stock_ws", "version": "2011-11-29", "login": self.login, "pwd": self.pwd},
            "getavailableshippingtypes": {"cat": "sales_ws", "version": "2013-06-25", "login": self.login,
                                          "pwd": self.pwd},
            "export": {"cat": "stock_ws", "version": "2014-11-04", "login": self.login, "pwd": self.pwd},
            "listing": {"cat": "listing_ssl_ws", "version": "2015-07-05", "login": self.login, "pwd": self.pwd},
            "categorymap": {"cat": "categorymap_ws", "version": "2011-10-11", "login": self.login, "pwd": self.pwd},
            "getnewsales": {"cat": "sales_ws", "version": "2016-03-16", "login": self.login, "pwd": self.pwd},
            "acceptsale": {"cat": "sales_ws", "version": "2010-09-20", "login": self.login, "pwd": self.pwd},
            "refusesale": {"cat": "sales_ws", "version": "2010-09-20", "login": self.login, "pwd": self.pwd},
            "getcurrentsales": {"cat": "sales_ws", "version": "2016-03-16", "login": self.login, "pwd": self.pwd},
            "getbillinginformation": {"cat": "sales_ws", "version": "2016-03-16", "login": self.login,
                                      "pwd": self.pwd},
            "getshippinginformation": {"cat": "sales_ws", "version": "2014-02-11", "login": self.login,
                                       "pwd": self.pwd},
            "getitemtodolist": {"cat": "sales_ws", "version": "2011-09-01", "login": self.login, "pwd": self.pwd},
            "getiteminfos": {"cat": "sales_ws", "version": "2011-06-01", "login": self.login, "pwd": self.pwd},
            "cancelitem": {"cat": "sales_ws", "version": "2011-02-02", "login": self.login, "pwd": self.pwd},
            "contactusaboutitem": {"cat": "sales_ws", "version": "2011-09-01", "login": self.login, "pwd": self.pwd},
            "contactuseraboutitem": {"cat": "sales_ws", "version": "2011-02-02", "login": self.login, "pwd": self.pwd},
            "settrackingpackageinfos": {"cat": "sales_ws", "version": "2016-03-16", "login": self.login,
                                        "pwd": self.pwd},
            "confirmpreorder": {"cat": "sales_ws", "version": "2013-01-09", "login": self.login, "pwd": self.pwd},
            "getoperations": {"cat": "wallet_ws", "version": "2011-03-29", "login": self.login, "pwd": self.pwd},
            "getcompensationdetails": {"cat": "sales_ws", "version": "2011-03-29", "login": self.login,
                                       "pwd": self.pwd}
        }

salestool = SalesManagement(init)`
```

And finally when renaming to lowercase:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\test.py", line 2, in <module>
    from shiba.shibaconnection import shibaconnection
  File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\shiba\shibaconnection.py", line 7, in <module>
    from shiba.salesmanagement import salesmanagement
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'shiba.salesmanagement'
```

and

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\alexa\Desktop\Amazon_API\z shiba test 2.py", line 2, in <module>
    from shiba.shibaconnection import shibaconnection
  File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\shiba\shibaconnection.py", line 7, in <module>
    from shiba.salesmanagement import salesmanagement
  File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\shiba\salesmanagement.py", line 6, in <module>
    from .shibaconnection import ShibaConnection
ImportError: cannot import name 'ShibaConnection'
```

Comment: Did you actually install Shiba?

Comment: yes. although always good to point out the obvious.

Comment: if using jupyter notebook its best to restart it after installing anew module

Comment: running windows and have done a restart.

Comment: `from shiba.shibaconnection import ShibaConnection`.  Module names are generally lowercase

Comment: are you sure you are using the right name, from installation looks like it has lowercase letter s

Comment: I did notice the lowercase difference and tried different combinations but still getting errors. The modules also use lowercase / uppercase combinations

Comment: One thing that is odd is why the error says there is no module name "Shiba" with capital S when nowhere in the import or the module itself is the word "Shiba" with capital S used...

Comment: What is the error you see with the lowercase version?  COuld you please post the full traceback in your question as text?